# Error on MySQL server with duplicate colunm name

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am getting this error:

```
    Notice: Error: Duplicate column name 'color' 
Error No: 1060
ALTER TABLE oc_hj_import ADD COLUMN (`color` BLOB NOT NULL ) in D:\xampp\htdocs\upload\system\database\mysql.php on line 50
```

This is the code:

```
public function alterImportTable($new_fields) {
    if (!empty($new_fields)) {
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE " . DB_PREFIX . "hj_import ADD COLUMN ";
        $fields_sql = array();
        foreach ($new_fields as $field) {
            $fields_sql[] = '`' . $field . "` BLOB NOT NULL ";
        }
        $sql .= '(' . implode(', ', $fields_sql) . ')';
        $sql = str_replace(', )', ')', $sql);
        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this array `$new_fields` it have double `color` or your table already have this field

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I found the reason for this problem. I have uppercase (Color) and lowercase (color) on the names. I need to difference that to add to the table. is it possible to make that on the sql?

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the column 'color' from your database or remove the 'color' from the $new_fields array or more so the array being passed to the function. Only problem is if you call this function twice with the same fields it will error out for column already existing :/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I found the reason for this problem. I have uppercase (Color) and lowercase (color) on the names. I need to difference that to add to the database. Is it possible to make in that code?

Comment: Not sure If I get what you're asking but if you mean you want to differentiate between 'Color' and 'color' I would just instead name the fields color1 and color2

Comment: Thanks. I had a crazy idea now. It is add a _ before of the uppercase. Something like this `$sql = str_replace('/\B([A-Z])/', '_$0', $sql);`. But it is not working. I am not sure if that is right or I am putting on the right place.